# Possible to make comment in quotes?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a comment within quotes.

```
"pizza,magic,dogs,hype"
```

Is it possible to comment out "magic," so the output would read:

```
"pizza,dogs,hype"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?
If you're testing something, why not comment out the whole string and add a new one the way you want it?

Comment: Rule of thumb: you can comment out anything that could have had whitespace in its place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest placing each word on a separate line:

```
"pizza,"
"magic,"
"dogs,"
"hype";
```

This allows you to comment words easier:

```
"pizza,"
/* "magic," */
"dogs,"
"hype";
```

The compiler will concatenate the string literals when separated by whitepace (and a newline is whitespace).

Comment: It's not actually necessary to put the words on separate lines, but it does make the code a bit clearer.

Comment: It's actually the preprocessor that merges string literals, otherwise a spot-on answer :)

Comment: Wow, I never knew that this could be done. Excellent.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can reword it thus:

```
"pizza,"/*magic,*/"dogs,hype"
```